# PHP smart || (OR) operator just like in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, types

Is it safe to use constructs like these in PHP:

`$filename = $file['filename1'] || $file['filename2'];`

I have a background in JS and this is safe to use since we can trust truthy/falsey values. However my colleague is used to constructs utilizing `isset`:

`$filename = 'filename'. (isset($file['filename2']) ? '2' : '1');`

Which to me seem a little verbose.

I found [an article on phabricator.com](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/PHP_Pitfalls.html) which outlines the different truthy/falsey values in PHP and offers this table:

```
VALUE             if()        empty()     isset()

null              false       true        false
0                 false       true        true
0.0               false       true        true
"0"               false       true        true
""                false       true        true
false             false       true        true
array()           false       true        true
EVERYTHING ELSE   true        false       true
```

I would appreciate anyone giving me insights in this matter.

Comment: the `||` and other comparative operators in php will return a BOOLEAN value, it will not act like it does in javascript.

Comment: @jeroen:hope you understand.accept the answer if you think its worthy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing:

```
$filename = $file['filename1'] || $file['filename2'];  //incorrect syntax
```

should be

```
$filename = $file['filename1'] || $filename = $file['filename2'];//depending on the condition
```

---

Second thing:

```
isset($file['filename2']) ? '2' : '1';
```

this is a shorthand which replaces verbose code.

same code can be written as:

```
if(isset($file['filename2']){
   $filename='filename2';
}else{
   $filename='filename1';
}
```

so,4 lines of code can be written in one line.Thats not verbose.Thats smart coding.

---

Third thing:

This is the ideal way of doing it.

```
return isset($file['filename2'])?$file['filename2']:$file['filename1'];
```

sample for understanding:

```
echo (age>18)?"where is my beer":"you are Underage!!!"; //codition:true:false
```

Answer (score 1):

the line

```
$filename = 'filename'. (isset($file['filename2']) ? '2' : '1');
```

is same as

```
if(isset($file['filename2']){
   $filename='filename2';
}else{
   $filename='filename1';
}
```

> || is used if you have multiple conditions in your if and if even one pf them is true, it'll be true.
>
> The ?: is a ternary operator

Comment: the edit you suggested is wrong..what i have done is correct for some valid reasons..what is filename1 and filename2.no $..no paranthesis..as i said,my answer is ideal for what the OP wants..

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random value from an array you can use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-rand.php), but if you want one value based on a condition you should use the ternary operator:

```
$filename = (condition) ? what_happens_if_true : what_happens_if_false;
```

Answer (score 1):

By using

`$filename = $file['filename1'] || $file['filename2'];`

if `$file['filename1']` isn't set, you'll receive an error such as `Undefined index: filename1'` since the (OR) operator will first check the first statement.

However, if `$file['filename1']` is set, but `$file['filename2']` isn't, the value `1` would be returned and no errors would be thrown, but your code would remain incorrect.

So, you'll want to go the `isset` way, or use (as pointed by VAGABOND):

`$filename = $file['filename1'] || $filename =$file['filename2'];`